# BouncyCastle Threefish - equal blocks ecnrypted equally

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, block-cipher

I am using Threefish of BouncyCastle directly, not via security API.

```
byte[] key = new byte[1024];
...
byte[] tweak = new byte[16];
...
ThreefishEngine threefishEngine = new ThreefishEngine(1024);
threefishEngine.init(true, new TweakableBlockCipherParameters(new KeyParameter(key), tweak));
...
threefishEngine.processBlock(...);
```

Interestingly, equal blocks will be encrypted in the same way. I have expected that the results of the previous block would affect the result of the next one (because key scheduling produces permanently different keys) and that same blocks will be encrypted differently.

In the source code of BouncyCastle, ThreefishEngine.java, tweak is used for encryption in the method encryptBlock, but tweak never changes. Also for encryption of the next block the previous is not used, neither original unencrypted block nor the encrypted block. In the ThreefishEngine there is no method to change the tweak after ThreefishEngine is initialized. Key scheduling in ThreefishEngine is done within single block only and has no effect for the encryption of the next block.

Here are the questions.

**1. Is that correct, that equal blocks produce equal encrypted blocks? Is my expectation wrong, that equal blocks should be encrypted differently?** Actually this is the essential difference between block and stream ciphers and otherwise that would be a stream cipher.

**2. Is key scheduling done withing a block only (different keys applied to different parts of the block)? Is key scheduling the same for each block?** That would explain why encrypted blocks are equal.

Comment: This question really belongs on our [Crypto site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). It sounds like you are confusing a block cipher *mode of operation*, like CBC or GCM, with the block cipher itself.

Comment: I agree. I would move it to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.